# How to simulatte MultipartException

Tags: java, file-upload, multipart

I get an exception:

```
WARN  exceptions - Handler execution resulted in exception
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:139)
```

during file upload and I don't have an idea what can I repeat this in my aplication. Did you know some tool for this? Or maybe you have some tips for me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [spring's unit test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/RequestParamMethodArgumentResolverTests.java) ?

```
@Test(expected=MultipartException.class)
public void isMultipartRequest() throws Exception {
     MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
     resolver.resolveArgument(paramMultipartFile, new ModelAndViewContainer(), new ServletWebRequest(request), null);
     fail("Expected exception");
}
```